Zkteco - ¿ Se puede generar una marcacion en un biométrico ZKTECO con la librería ZKEMKEEPER.dll?
Zkteco - ¿ Se puede generar una marcacion en un biométrico ZKTECO con la librería ZKEMKEEPER.dll?
Obtener los registros, agregar usuarios y basicamente muchas otras funcionalidades se puede realizar pero mi duda es si se puede simular una marcacion de un usuario mediante la libreria.

no se puede, seria un backdoor
